# Rasa Response selector training issue

Tags: python, rasa

I am building FAQ Bot using rasa but i am facing training issue with Response selector.Diet classifier training taking 40min with 20k FAQs and accuracy=0.99 but response selector training taking 1 day for 100 epoch with GPU and accuracy is very low 0.048.can you please guide me how can i improve this response selector part. Why its taking so much time for training. When i am using small data like 100 FAQs its working fine with same code. When i used 20k FAQ .for any question its giving only one answer.i am using RASA 2.1.

Comment: It's very hard to help you debug this without getting additional context. Could you start a question on https://forum.rasa.com with your config.yml listed? If you could also share any information on what kinds of intents/responses that would also help. Feel free to ping my username there: @koaning.